# Multiple textbox validation in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I would like to check if exists any empty textBox on my Window. I found pretty nice solution for windowForms

```
if(this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Any(t => string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Text)) {
...
}
```

by @StriplingWarrior

What is equivalent of this.Control in WPF? How to solve it in smart way?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(p_Parent).OfType<TextBox>().ToList().Where(d => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(d.Text)).ToList();
```

I have used it various places. Hope it helps.